# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '1 2 3 4 5'

Tags: python

this is the code just to find some sort of product :print the product of all the number in this array Modulo 10^9+7

```
         n=int(input())
            answer=1
            b=10**9
            array_1=[]
            for i in range(n):
                array_1.append(int(input()))
            for j in range(n):
                answer=(answer*array_1[j])% (b+7)
            print(answer)
```

this my code in python 3 working properly in jupyter notebook, but on 
                python (3.5.2) it is showing error for  input 5 and then 1 2 3 4 5

```
        Execution failed.
        ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '1 2 3 4 5'

        Stack Trace:


        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/hackerearth/PYTHON3_46/s_ad.py3", line 16, in 
        array_1.append(int(input()))
        ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'
```

please some one help me to solve this error as i m newbie in python

Comment: What line is line 16? I'd assume it's `array_1.append(int(input()))` and `input()` is the value `'1 2 3 4 5'`? If so it's because it doesn't know how to cast what you have into a number.

Comment: Your input is wrong. First **line** should be number/count of numbers that gonna enter, and the next lines should be the numbers you want to check

Comment: array_1.append(int(input()))  by  using this i m trying  to get an array of integer by taking value one by one from user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> array_1.append(int(input())) by using this i m trying get an array of int by 
>   taking value one by one from user input –

But it looks like you are entering the numbers one after the other as a single string with each number separated by a space. In that case, you should use split to get the individual numbers:

```
array_of_ints = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
array_1 += array_of_ints
```

If you are trying to input the numbers one by one, your code seems correct. You just need to make sure you actually do enter the numbers one by one.
i.e. 1 then press Enter, 2 then press Enter, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but just based on looking at it, your code would not accept any of the inputs after `1 2`

If you are running this from a terminal, there should be a new line between each input, i.e.

```
./your_program.py
4
4
3
2
1
```